# Conversion of unsigned char array to bitmap in MFC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I tried to convert from unsigned char array to Bitmap in MFC as follow.

```
        BITMAPFILEHEADER* bmfh;
        bmfh = (BITMAPFILEHEADER*)rgbByte;

        BITMAPINFOHEADER* bmih;
        bmih = (BITMAPINFOHEADER*)(rgbByte + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
        BITMAPINFO* bmi;
        bmi = (BITMAPINFO*)bmih;

        void* bits;
        bits = (void*)(rgbByte + bmfh->bfOffBits);

        HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);

        HBITMAP hbmp = CreateDIBitmap(hdc, bmih, CBM_INIT, bits, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS) ;
```

rgbByte is my unsigned char array and the problem is hbmp is always unused and never get data. What is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, with "is always unused and never get data". Is hbmp created? If so it has its own copy of your pixels you provided.

Answer (score 0):

```
HDC hdc = ::GetDC(NULL);
```

gets the DC of the entire screen. I doubt that is what you want. More likely you have a window or image control into which you want to place the bitmap. You need to get the DC of that window instead by passing to GetDC() it's `m_hWnd` member.

Comment: If he just wants to create a bitmap, there is nothing wrong in using a screen DC.

Comment: I changed to HDC hdc = ::GetDC(pImageORG->m_hWnd);But hdc is NULL so hbmp is still NULL.